# xdebug running in PHPStorm unable to connect to remote server

Tags: php, debugging, phpstorm, xdebug, remote-debugging

### Problem

I'm trying to get xdebug running between my box and a webapp running on a remote server.

I'm running xdebug through PHPStorm on my development box. I get stuck after starting the debugger. The PHPStorm debugger window hangs on "Waiting for incoming connection with ide key 'PHPStorm'"

### Remote Server Configs

On the remote server, our sys admin has installed xdebug. The server has the following settings:

```
xdebug.remote_port  9000
xdebug.default_enable   On  
xdebug.remote_enable    On
xdebug.remote_connect_back  On
```

Note that remote_connect_back is on. I'm configuring this for a multi-developer environment. This will cause xdebug.remote_host to be ignored (which is why I didn't include it up there).

I'm using the Firefox "The Easiest xdebug" addon. If I refresh a page with the xdebug addon disabled, the page loads just fine.

If I enable the addon for that page and refresh, the page will hang until timeout. I believe this tells me that xdebug is running and at least TRYING to do something. Right? So far so good.

### Client Configs

I'm running PHPStorm on my local dev box. I have also installed xdebug on my dev box. Here's some relevant output from php -i:

```
xdebug support => enabled
xdebug.default_enable => On => On
xdebug.idekey => PHPStorm => PHPStorm
xdebug.remote_enable => On => On
xdebug.remote_port => 9000 => 9000
xdebug.remote_host => localhost => localhost
xdebug.remote_connect_back => Off
```

I'm using xdebug version 2.2.3 on the server and 2.2.7 on the client. I need to use old versions, because we're stuck on PHP 5.3... at least for now. Both client and server are running PHP 5.3.

In PHPStorm, I set up a server config connecting to the remote server:

devops-dev.ourcloud.com

I have a path mapping to an absolute path on the server: var/www/api/apidev.ourcloud.com/current

Waiting on port 9000. I have my IDEKey in PHPStorm set to "PHPStorm".

### Results

I click the phone to listen for debugger connections and click the green debugger icon, and in the debugger view, I see:

Waiting for incoming connection with ide key 'PHPStorm'

And that's it. I don't seem to be connecting to the server.

Any clue what's causing this or even how I might be able to better debug this?

Comment: could be a communications issue , ie remote server disables outbound port 9000, or your dev box/router blocks 9000 inbound. maybe , just a wag

Comment: Yves, thanks! There indeed seems to be a firewall issue. Might not be the only problem, but it's at least **A** problem.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was a firewall problem. I was able to fix the problem by running an ssh tunnel from my client to my server:

ssh -f -N -T -R9000:localhost:9000 theserver

I was also able to find this issue using netcat from the server to the client.

From server: nc client 9000

That showed that the port was blocked.